# python pandas assign values to column based on formula

Tags: python, pandas

I have a formula as a text that is generated on the fly (dynamic)

```
formula = "(-500) + 7.7* df['A'] + -0.1234 * df['B']"
```

the formula is a text string and it is configured at run time, but it will always have dependency on existing other fields.

I would like to use this formaul to create a new field df['calculated'] that is based on this formula.

I looked at panada.apply(), map(), assign(), but I still can't get it to work.

Please advise if there a way to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pd.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and eval

```
formula = "(-500) + 7.7 * df['A'] + -0.1234 * df['B']"
df = df.assign(calculated=eval(formula))
```